# How to determine if a MB JTEXT adapter is up remotely

Tags: messagebroker

I need to make sure that the JTEXT adapter on a remote server is available (from my PC), but I have no idea how to do that. I don't have any MB software on my computer, and I'm wondering if there is a way to determine if it is available, possibly via telnet or some similar measure.

Secondly, if there IS a way to determine the stats of a JTEXT adapter remotely, how do I figure out what port is being used for the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the JText adapter is a Java process running on your server, so yes, in theory you should be able to SSH in to the server and check the process list. Right now I can't remember what you'll want to grep for in the process list but it should be reasonably obvious.

The port will have been specified in the adapter's configuration file. Probably worth checking with your administrator to see where that is.